# JavaScript animation causing bright screen flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the jQuery library 'transitions' for its extension in simply CSS tweening. The issue, however, comes when I simply try to hide or remove the backdrop (which causes the area around the appearing content to get darker).

When I hide/remove the backdrop, the original site underneath it "flashes" with a bright color before returning to its original dark scheme.

Webpage in question (just click one of the TV shows to make the backdrop appear, then click anywhere off of it to witness the removal + flashing) : [Webpage in Question](http://animeandmangaclub.net/?Page=AnimeDirectory)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#MetaContent").transition({scale:[0,0]});
        $(".AMResultSelector").click(function(){
            var Title = $(this).children("span").html();
            var CoverPhoto = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
            var Description = $(this).children("p").html();

            $("#MetaTitle").html(Title);
            $("#MetaCoverPhoto").attr('src', CoverPhoto);
            $("#MetaSummary").html(Description);
            $("#AMMetaGoTo").children("a").attr("href", "/?Page=ViewAnime&ID=" + $(this).attr("data-media-id"));

            //Center it
            setTimeout(function(){
                var CWidth = $("#AMMetaPreviewBox").width();
                var CHeight = $("#AMMetaPreviewBox").height();
                var OffsetX = $("#MetaContent").width()/2;
                var OffsetY = $("#MetaContent").height()/2;
                console.log(OffsetX);
                $("#MetaContent").css("left", (CWidth/2 - OffsetX) + "px");
                $("#MetaContent").css("top", (CHeight/2 - OffsetY) + "px");
            }, 10);
            $("#AMMetaPreviewBox").show();
            $("#MetaContent").transition({scale:[1,1]}, 200);
        })

        $("#AMMetaPreviewBox").click(function(){
            $("#MetaContent").transition({scale:[0,0]}, 200, function(){ $("#AMMetaPreviewBox").hide() });
        })
    })
</script>
```

I don't understand why this is happening...

> Browser: Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: Share the code along with the HTML content  in a fiddle

Comment: The content given in the URL in the original post should suffice to show the problem while being easy to edit without a fiddle.

Comment: No flickering here, same version of Chrome.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's my monitor. After some mobile tests on a tablet and phone (my only other options for testing) it doesn't seem to happen on them. Using an LCD monitor via HDMI. It's a bit aged, so it might be the issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about screen flickering due to monitor failure.